# Importing and evaluating notebook from plain text

Tags: import, evaluation, notebooks

I have a computer-generated **plain text** file with some Wolfram Language definitions separated by newline characters - imagine it is the code you would type to a single cell:

```
shape1 = Polygon{{0,1},{1,2},{-5,6}};

shape2 = Polygon{{0,-1},{5,-3},{5,9}};
```

I'd like to programmatically open this file in a notebook and evaluate the code so that `shape1` and `shape2` are accessible in this notebook. I tried different combinations of `CreateDocument[]`, `Import[]` and `EvaluateNotebook[]` but nothing works the way I'd like to.

What should I do? It is possible to make some changes in this generated file, since it's done by a program of mine, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: The syntax  in the file seems to be incorrect. It should read `string = "shape1 = Polygon[{{0,1},{1,2},{-5,6}}];
 
 shape2 = Polygon[{{0,-1},{5,-3},{5,9}}];"`. Having the correct string, `ToExpression[string]` works fine. Actually, `Get[<<filename>>]` should also work once the syntax has been corrected.

Comment: Actually this plain text file is saved with extension *.nb and opening it in Mathematica produces a correct notebook. I can for example click SHIFT+ENTER and get the contents evaluated correctly.

Comment: However doing `ToExpression@Import["thefile.nb","Text"]` did it's job, thanks. I would give +1 but I cannot yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Get["file.txt"]` which reads in a file, evaluating each expression in it and returning the last one.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html